# Laplacian Equation in general

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

Say, I have a function $\phi$ of two variables ($x$ and $y$)
My objective is not to solve this equation exactly but to look for the order of terms.
I know that the scalar $\phi$ has following variation,

$\phi(x,y)= \phi(y) + \partial^2 _{x}\phi \ x^2$

Note that $\partial^2 \phi _{x}$ is only a function of y.

Now say my $f(y)$ is following,

$\Delta \phi = f(y)$

My objective here is to get some estimations of $f(y)$ based on the nature of  $\phi$ I mentioned above. Is there anything I can say about $f(y)$ or/and $\partial_y f(y)$?